# Como utilizar un modelo en Django sin PK

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

Tengo la tabla Pedidos que contiene los campos cod_pedido (pk) y cod_usuario.
luego tengo una tabla llamada detalle_pedido que **NO** tiene pk. En esta tabla se guarda la pk del pedido y todos los productos que se pidieron.
A la hora de hacer un Detalle_pedidos.objects.all() me tira el siguiente error
**(1054, "Unknown column 'detalle_pedido.id' in 'field list'")**

este es mi modelo:

```
class Detalle_pedido(models.Model):
    pedido_id = models.ForeignKey(Pedido, to_field="cod_pedido", db_column="pedido_id", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cod_art = models.ForeignKey(Stock, db_column="cod_art", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cant_pedida = models.IntegerField()
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'detalle_pedido'
```

mi idea es hacer un object.filter con el codigo del pedido, pero hago el Print(Detalle_pedidos.objects.all()) y ya me salta error

Comment: Sólo un comentario tonto: ¿no sería más fácil si hicieras un PK? Por defecto, Django añade una columna "id" a cada modelo como clave primaria si no se especifica una. En tu modelo Order_Detail, no has definido una clave primaria explícitamente, así que deberías tener una columna id que pudieras usar...

Comment: seria la solucion mas facil... agregar una pk autoincremental y listo. Pero esa tabla solamente sirve para ver que productos estan en el pedido que se realizo. ¿no hay alguna forma de utilizar django sin que me pida una PK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django requiere que cada modelo tenga una clave primaria (PK). Si no se especifica una PK en el modelo, Django creará automáticamente un campo id como PK. En tu caso, el modelo Detalle_pedido no tiene una PK definida, por lo que Django intenta buscar el campo id por defecto, que no existe, y por eso obtienes el error.

Si no quieres agregar una PK autoincremental a tu modelo Detalle_pedido, puedes considerar usar un MultiColumn Primary Key (Clave Primaria de Múltiples Columnas). Django no soporta directamente las PK de múltiples columnas, pero puedes usar una combinación de campos para simular este comportamiento. Para hacer esto, puedes agregar la opción unique_together en la clase Meta de tu modelo. Aquí te dejo un ejemplo:

```
class Detalle_pedido(models.Model):
    pedido_id = models.ForeignKey(Pedido, to_field="cod_pedido", db_column="pedido_id", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cod_art = models.ForeignKey(Stock, db_column="cod_art", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cant_pedida = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'detalle_pedido'
        unique_together = (("pedido_id", "cod_art"),)
```

En este caso, la combinación de pedido_id y cod_art debe ser única para cada registro en la tabla Detalle_pedido, lo que simula el comportamiento de una PK de múltiples columnas. Sin embargo, ten en cuenta que aunque esto puede resolver tu problema actual, puede que no sea la mejor práctica dependiendo de tu caso de uso específico. Siempre es recomendable tener una PK en cada tabla para mantener la integridad de los datos y facilitar las operaciones de la base de datos.